# How to use navCtrl.push() using a variable that contains a class name?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic3

I'm working with Visual Studio Code on Ionic 3 and AngularJS/Typescript.
I use this.navCtrl.push() to jump to another page.
I have two classes/pages i need to jump to, they are called "level1" and "level2". when i use

```
this.navCtrl.push(level2)
```

it works fine!
however when i use a variable:

```
levelNbr: any;

if(value == null)
{
   this.levelNbr = "level1"
}
else
{
   this.levelNbr = "level2"
}

this.navCtrl.push(this.levelNbr)
```

I get an error saying:

> Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: level2

This means its actually reading level2. however its not opening the page.
How is it possible to open/push the page using a variable?

Thank you

Adding used code:

```
import { level1 } from './../levels/levels';
import { level2 } from './../levels/levels';
//all classes are in one file called levels
```

in the app.modules.ts they are declared as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So loading (pushing into the stack in your case) of new components/pages would work exactly the way you did it in cases where you use "lazy loading" for those components.

Apparently (since you are getting invalid link error) you are not in this case using lazy loading.

So to help your case you need to import relevant components into the Component you are trying to perform this from and assign Components:

```
import { Level1Component } from '../whatever";
import { Level2Coomponent } from '../whatever2";

...
if(value == null)
{
   this.levelNbr = Level1Component
}
else
{
   this.levelNbr = Level2Component
}

this.navCtrl.push(this.levelNbr)
```

And of course such imported Components (levels) should be declared properly in you overall app's module (app.module.ts)

Comment: I have that declared already, however you solved my problem!!! the problem was that i was writing this.levelNbr = "Level1Component" instead of this.levelNbr = Level1Component therefor thanks a lot!

Comment: ;) glad to help.